# Telnet returns Name or service not known

Tags: telnet

I'm trying to telnet from Centos 7 to Centos 6.8 on port 1521:

`#telnet 192.168.1.100 1521`

And I get the following error

`telnet: 192.168.1.100:1521: Name or service not known
192.168.1.100:1521: Unknown host`

Firewall is disable on both machines.
Selinux is disabled on both machines.
Ping is working fine on both machines.

Comment: Are you sure you typed `telnet 192.168.1.100 1521` (correct)? Or did you type `telnet 192.168.1.100:1521` (wrong)?

Comment: as you see in the question i typed `telnet 192.168.1.100 1521`

Comment: I asked because I get a similar error message when I use a colon `:` between IP address and port number instead of whitespace. Your error message means that `telnet` was not able to resolve a host name `192.168.1.100:1521` which apparently is the combination of an IP address and a port number. If you really separated IP address and port number with space: Do you have an alias or function named `telnet`?

Comment: On Debian telnet separates host and port in an error message with a `/` eg: `telnet: could not resolve example.com/1521: Name or service not known`.  So if you really did call `telnet 192.168.1.100 1521` then what version of telnet are you using and on what operating system.

Comment: 1) I see no reason to DV, 2) I don't have centos available, but in redhat that looks like correct syntax. 3) what is the result of `whereis telnet` and `alias telnet` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a RHEL7 system, typing `telnet 192.168.1.100:1521` results in exactly your error message:

```
telnet: 192.168.1.100:1521: Name or service not known
192.168.1.100:1521: Unknown host
```

... so it seems likely to me that there was an accidental copy/paste of the command with a colon instead of a space:

```
telnet 192.168.1.100 1521
```

Tested with:

```
rpm -qf $(type -p telnet)
telnet-0.17-64.el7.x86_64
```